# Shibboleth - Is it possible to move a site between computers without reissuing metadata

Tags: iis, single-sign-on, saml, shibboleth

I have a site that implements a Shibboleth SSO. When the metadata was issued from the service provider to pass to the IdP I saw that the Metadata had the machine name in it. I need to know if moving this site to a new server with a different machine name means that the metadata will need to be reissued to the IdP.

Machine setup is Windows/IIS